# deployments on elastic beanstalk PHP 7.4 running on 64bit always fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

I am trying to deploy a simple php applicaton (at the moment I just trying to deploy an info.php file) on AWS elastic beanstalk PHP 7.4 running on 64bit and it always fails.
The logs are not clear at all to me, this is what I get:

```
2021-11-16 08:59:04 UTC+0000    
ERROR
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2021-11-16 08:59:04 UTC+0000    
ERROR
Failed to deploy application.
2021-11-16 08:59:04 UTC+0000    
ERROR
Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-09c35678ec1d7167c'. Aborting the operation.
2021-11-16 08:59:04 UTC+0000    
INFO
Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

2021-11-16 08:59:04 UTC+0000
ERROR
[Instance: i-09c35678ec1d7167c] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..

I also checked the causes and same thing, not clear for me.

[image]

NOTE: **the simple phpinfo() file is working now**, but the application that it was working before on php 7.3 it is not working on this php 7.4 env. But I have it working without errors in a docker php7.4 docker container, that's why I not understand.

[image]
Any idea where the issue can be?
Thanks

Comment: SSH into Elastic Beanstalk powered ec2 instance and check the logs at the file /var/log/eb-engine.log. You will find more error logs here.